# How to pass in a list of generic Objects?

Tags: c#, .net

I have an object with the following:

```
public class ExpenseFilters<T> {
    public ExpenseFilterType Type {get;set;}
    public T Value {get;set;}
}
```

T can be a string, int, decimal in this case.

I want to create a method that accepts a generic list of ExpenseFilters:

```
public void DoSomething(List<ExpenseFilters<T>> filterList) {}
```

Is this possible somehow?

EDIT: Apologies as I wasn't being clear enough.

I want the List of ExpenseFilters to not be constrained to one generic type.

For example, the list should contain

```
ExpenseFilters<int>
```

as well as

```
ExpenseFilters<string>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the method generic:

```
public void DoSomething<T>(List<ExpenseFilters<T>> filterList) { }
```

When you use this method, the type parameter `T` can usually be inferred by the compiler, so you don't even need to specify it:

```
List<ExpenseFilters<int>> list = new List<ExpenseFilters<int>>();
DoSomething(list);
```

**Edit**

Turns out it's not what you wanted to do.

It's not possible to do it with generics. The closest thing you might do is to create a non-generic interface or base class implemented/inherited by the generic one.

```
public interface IExpenseFilters
{
    ExpenseFilterType Type { get; set; }
    object Value { get; set; }
}

public class ExpenseFilters<T> : IExpenseFilters
{
    public ExpenseFilterType Type { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }

    object IExpenseFilters.Value
    {
        get { return Value; }
        set
        {
            if (!(value is T))
                throw new ArgumentException("Incorrect type", "value");
            Value = (T)value;
        }
    }
}
```